# Which Runners support kafkaIO in apache beam?

Tags: apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I am working with apache beam. My task is to pull data from kafka topic and process in dataflow.
Does dataflow support kafkaIO ?
Which runners are supported for KafkaIO ?

Comment: was the answer helpful?

Comment: @Pablo, conceptually its ok., but practically i'll need to research more about runner_v2.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. KafkaIO is supported by Dataflow and other major Beam runners.

We have Kafka transforms for both [Java](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/kafka/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/kafka/KafkaIO.java) and [Python](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/kafka.py) SDKs.

Note that Python versions are [cross-language transforms](https://beam.apache.org/roadmap/connectors-multi-sdk/) and Dataflow requires [runner V2](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/deploying-a-pipeline#dataflow-runner-v2).

Comment: Thanks @chamikara, as per apache beam documentation,  ' --experiments=use_runner_v2 '   is the parameter we need to pass for using RunnerV2. 
Is it enough or i need to make changes in my code?   sorry i am new to apache beam.

Comment: It should be enough. You also need Java installed in the pipeline from where the job is being submitted. We are adding an example to Beam which should clarify this better.